# Timeout when importing an excel file into database

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I'm trying to import excel files to my MySQL database on Laravel 5.4 with the PHPExcel-based [Maatwebsite/laravel-excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) library.

The files I need to import are pretty big: at least 50k rows with 100 columns, and I need to create a database entry for each row.

I thought I may have some problems with the import process, so I started out with using chunks, however even at 1 chunks I get the following error message:

> Maximum execution time of 180 seconds exceeded.

I tried to increase the `max_execution_time` variable and memory limit, but I still can't seem to go through with the import.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($request->file('source_file')->getRealPath())->chunk(1,function ($results) {
    foreach($results as $row) {
        TaskMeta::create([
         'task_id' => $row['task_id'],
         'col2' => $row['column2'],
         ... etc, rest of the 100 columns ommited for clarity
        ]);
    }
});
```

I'm testing this locally in my Homestead environment by the way. I need a solution that would work on a production server as well.

Comment: How do you run this command: from the console or through web server? And when did you change `max_execution_time` for cli or for apache? thx.

Comment: I changed max_execution_time in my apache server's php.ini file. I don't want to increase it further though - I need to simulate a production environment to make sure it'll work.

Comment: And you dont want change any settings on production env in php.ini. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, it would be a huge pain to maintain good security with a higher max execution time.

Comment: Have you looked at the "chunking" options for Maatwebsite/laravel-excel at all, that allow you to split the file across multiple loads, loading different parts ("chunks") with each

Comment: I'm using chunks in my code example. I tried setting the chunk # it as low as 1, but I still get the timeout.

Comment: Is using ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000) before `Excel::filter('chunk')` acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the timeout just for this script use:

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

...and monitor your processes to make sure it's not hanging. Maybe even put it into a Command and use $this->info() to output the row number for every iteration so you know where it's at in the file.

This way you override any .ini config that may be holding you back :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php